# Обратиться к заранее неизвестному элементу в js

Tags: javascript, html

Есть nodelist ul с элементами li. Нужно проверить, какой li отвечает ему и добавить класс именно этому элементу.
Как можно обратиться к нужному li?
Нужен только нативный js.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let yes = document.querySelectorAll('.yes');

for( let i = 0; i < yes.length; i++ ) {
  let li = yes[i].querySelectorAll('li');  
  for( let j = 0; j < li.length; j++ ) {
    li[j].classList.add('red');
  }  
}
```

```css
.red {color: red;}
```

```html
<ul class="yes">
  <li>11</li>
  <li>22</li>
</ul>

<ul class="no">
  <li>33</li>
  <li>44</li>
</ul>

<ul class="yes">
  <li>55</li>
  <li>66</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: салам, ты здесь ?

Comment: @MaximLensky хшш...хшш...есть связь)

Comment: меня всё равно мучает ..как ты перебрал nodelist for ааа ?почему это сработало ?

Comment: @MaximLensky о_О а что должно было помешать? `yes[0].querySelectorAll('li');` — достает все li внутри первого ul.yes... Достал li - перебрал, покрасил - пошел дальше. `yes[1].querySelectorAll('li');` — все li внутри второго.

Comment: thank you... I just started learning javascript and for me it's crazy because I learn everything alphabetically and can't ask about every little thing on so

Comment: @MaximLensky It's a common practice) For loop just takes the code, and executes it as many times, as he was told. And variable `i` (or any other) - is just a number on each iteration, which can be used to get an array element, in math operations, etc — https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/vgok9be8/ (demo)

Comment: I got it, thank you but I thought that nodeList can only be sorted out forach